# Copying text of textarea in clipboard when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, textarea

I'm looking to create a jQuery (or javascript) `button` that selects everything in a `textarea` and then copies the text to your `clipboard` when you clicked on button.

I have found some examples using the focus event. But I'm looking for a button that you actually have to click for the select and copy.

How can i do this work?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to use [`select()`](https://api.jquery.com/select/) to selecting text of `textarea` and use [`execCommand('copy')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) to coping selected text. Its work in upper version of browsers.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("textarea").select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

Also you can do this work **without jquery** as shown in bottom

```
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector("textarea").select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function(){
  document.querySelector("textarea").select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
};
```

```html
<button>Select</button>
<br/>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: The newline is not preserved while copying in IE9

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if the `textarea` element is marked as `disabled` the above won't work so you need to remove the disabled attribute beforehand.

Comment: If the textarea is hidden by "display: none" the copy doesn't work. Removing the style attribute before copying and adding it afterwards again works fine for me.

Comment: **NOTE**: This is now deprecated, see the "Modern Solution" below

Answer (score 26):

It is possible to make this without using jQuery.

Here's a pure js solution.

```js
function copy() {
  let textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
  textarea.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works using your exact code, but when I put the <textarea></textarea> inside <details></details>, the contents don't copy.

Comment: Interesting to note, that if you put `textarea.setSelectedRange(0,99999)` like W3Schools recommends (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp), it doesn't work.

Comment: I found that while this worked on Windows, it didn't work on Mac using Safari

Answer (score 10):

## Modern Solution

`document.execCommand('copy')` is now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Instead, we now have the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API)

You can use the `writeText()` property to accomplish this:

```js
$('button').on('click', () => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText($('textarea').val()).then(
    () => {
      console.log('clipboard successfully set');
    },
    () => {
      console.error('clipboard write failed');
    }
  );
});
```

or just simply:

```js
$('button').on('click', () => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText($('textarea').val());
});
```

**Bonus**: This works with disabled textareas and is cross-browser compatible

Answer (score 2):

When your textarea element has disabled for some reason, or if you don't want to visual effect of selected texts, then the solution below works for you.

```
$("#button_id").click(function(){
    var $temp = $("<textarea></textarea>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($("#textarea_source").val()).select();     <-- #textarea_source: id of textarea source to be copied to the clipboard
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Copying text of textarea**
<textarea id="text" class="form-control" rows="21" cols="40" name="text">
                This word has two main meanings. The first has to do with being pleased and satisfied (feeling content) or making someone else feel happy and at peace with things (contenting them). The other meaning has to do with subject matter: the content of a history class might be American history. The content of a math class might be geometry. As long as there's a topic or subject, there's content.
</textarea>
**The following code added to script area**
$("button").click(function(){
      $("textarea").select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      });
```

Comment: What is the point of copying the same answer as the one selected as answer?