# Copy to clipboard from textarea in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to copy text from a HTML textarea, however I only found a solution with an Input tag like this:

```
<input type="text" value="User input Text to copy" #userinput>
<button (click)="copyInputMessage(userinput)" value="click to copy">Copy from Textbox</button>
```

Function:

```
copyInputMessage(inputElement){
  inputElement.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
}
```

When I want to replace the input tag with a textarea tag it doesn’t work anymore.
Is there an similar easy solution with a textarea?

Comment: can you post the *not working* code?

Comment: have a look on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658524/copying-text-of-textarea-in-clipboard-when-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvfpr6?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<textarea type="text" #userinput></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="4" [(ngModel)] = "userinput"></textarea>




<button (click)="copyInputMessage()" value="click to copy">Copy from Textbox</button>
```

Create a Variable in Ts file As String And Using Property binding bind this with Text area value

```
 userinput: string;


copyInputMessage(this.userinput){
  inputElement.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
}
```

if You want to use template reference then

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="4" #userinput></textarea>
```

in Ts file

```
@ViewChild('userinput') nameInputRef: ElementRef;
```

Comment: why to use `[(ngModel)]` instead `template reference variable`?

Comment: Explain that in the answer!